# Regex how get url() Content

Tags: c#, css, regex, url

Hi all I'm trying to parse css url's with regex but anything fails..

```
Regex cssUrls = new Regex(@"url\((?<char>['""])?(?<url>.*?)\k<char>?\)");


foreach (var item in cssUrls.Matches("@import url(pepe/global.css);"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
}
```

The output is: `url(pepe/global.css)` but i need that: `pepe/global.css`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Matches` in `cssUrls.Matches` object holds all of the matched string, therefore item.ToString() gives the whole match.  You want something like `item.Groups["url"].Value` to extract only `url` named part of the match.

Comment: item doesn't have the "groups" property.

Comment: Change your `var` into `Match` in the `foreach` declaration so it knows that `item` will be a `Match`.

Comment: Not a problem, that's what SO is for. It is a little weird that it doesn't detect that item will be a `Match`, I guess its because MatchCollection implements `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<Match>`.

Answer (score 0):

Possible alternative solution, partially implemented with regex and string manipulation.

```
Regex cssUrls = new Regex(@"\(['"]?(?<url>[^)]+?)['"]?\)");

foreach (var item in cssUrls.Matches("@import url(pepe/global.css);"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.TrimStart("(").TrimEnd(")").ToString());
}
```